# Check when the Calender Ajax extension is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a Calentder Ajax Extension in my webpage. And a textbox displaying the date selected.

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Width="90px""></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCallDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="pic/Calendar.png" 
          ImageAlign="Baseline" Height="16px" /> 
          <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalToDate2" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDate" 
          Format="yyyy/MM/dd" PopupButtonID="imgCallDate"  StartDate="2013/09/01"
    OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkDate()"
          > 
           </asp:CalendarExtender> 

       ....
     <asp:Button ID="Find" runat="server" Text="OK" onclick="Find_Click"  />
```

with

```
<script>
        function checkDate(sender, args) {
            if (sender._selectedDate.getDay=="")
            {

                    alert("You have to choose one date");
            }}
</script>
```

On  `OnClientDateSelectionChanged` call `checkDate()` function to show the alert when the client click the button `Find` without choose a date in Calendar. 
But it seem the function `checkDate()` is wrong. Not any Alert is showed even when I didnt choose the Date in Calendar.

I'm a new to ASP.Net?
Is there any mistake in my codes above???

I just think the problem is this line:  `if (sender._selectedDate.getDay=="")`

Comment: Is that the entire script? If it is, the problem is most likely the missing `}`. Put that at the end of the script, before the `</script>` tag, and it will maybe start working.

Comment: oh, I missed that } when I copied from my project. Take a look at my update

Comment: You made mistake at sender._selectedDate not  sender._selectedDate.getDay

Comment: Avinash: I've tried with sender._selectedDate=="", but it doesn't work

Comment: Based on the answer, `_selectedDate` might be null, which isn't quite the same as `""`. Try it with `if (!sender._selectedDate) {` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
 <title>Ajax Calendar Control</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckDate(sender,args) {
        if (sender._selectedDate) {
             alert("no date selected!");
             sender._selectedDate = new Date();
             // set the date to the today
             sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Should that be `if (!sender._selectedDate)`?

Comment: it still doesn't work. I put this <script></script> in the end of <asp:content> of my webpage, is that right? But I still doesn't work. When I insert that <script> and click on the Immage Calender, all the page load again.

Comment: You need to put that Script block in the head section of the page

Comment: Put debugger key word at the java script function call, to check whether it is hitting the function or not..also check the name of the function whether it is specified correctly

Comment: I add Event: OnClientDateSelectionChanged=CheckDate(), then click on the  imgCallDate to select date, but when I click on the imgCallDate-> the page load again, just load page again nothing happen. I really dont know why???

Comment: Is that hitting the java script function?

Comment: @Avinash no, it isn't